# c# Custom Attribute with support for string resources does not load localized resources

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

I have a DLL containing this custom attibutes

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class MyAttribute: System.Attribute {

private ResourceManager resManager = null;

public MyAttribute() {
}

public Type ResourceType { get; set; }

private string caption = string.Empty;
public string Caption {
  get { return getResourceString(caption); }
  set { caption = value; }
} //Caption

private string getResourceString(string resourceKey) {

  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(resourceKey))
    return string.Empty;

  if (ResourceType == default(Type))
    return resourceKey;

  if (resManager == null)
    resManager = new ResourceManager(ResourceType);

  return resManager.GetString(resourceKey) ?? string.Format("[[{0}]]", resourceKey);

} //getResourceString()
```

}

And a program (exe) that use the MyAttribute and also has the resources needed (resKeyHello) for both english and french in *Resources.resx* and *Resources.fr.resx* respectively

```
[MyAttribute(Caption="resKeyHello", ResourceType=typeof(Resources)]
public Foo() {
}
```

The problem is that it never use the french satellite assembly.  I also tried to create the ResourceManager like this **ResourceManager(ResourceType.FullName, ResourceType.Assembly)**, but without any effect.  And also tried loading the resource like this **resManager.GetString(resourceKey, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture)**

I can see in debugger that CurrentUICulture is french.

Comment: For me, using logic in attributes this way is a bad design choice. Attributes are meant to be just metadata.

Comment: @Matias, so how do you localize your attibutes ?  Is not the way Entity Framework localize validation attributes ?

Comment: Likely error is in the code that actually calls your `Caption` method - showing that along with name of  `CurrentUICulture` at that point could help...

Comment: @DonaldLeclerc I don't know how I would do it, but attributes should be used in code to perform decisions rather than doing them in the attribute itself.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer, thanx, I get it know.  So I moved the code from the CustomAttribute to the Method using it.  Unfortunately, I still get the same problem.

Comment: @DonaldLeclerc This another story... I didn't tell you that moving the code would solve the issue, but at least, your code is in the right track in terms of software architecture...

Comment: Finally, the problem was about the way french resources file were generated.  I used Project -> New -> Resources file with same name and .fr.resx extension.  The satellite DLL were generated during compilation in the ./bin/fr sub folder, but the runtime did not see it.  Finally I used "ResX Resource Manager" from CodePlex to generate my resource files and now everything is ok.  Thanx to all for your time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found a workaround.

The problem seem to be about the way french resources file were generated. I used Project -> New -> Resources file with same name and .fr.resx extension.

The satellite DLL were generated during compilation in the ./bin/fr sub folder, but the runtime did not see it.

Finally I used "ResX Resource Manager" from CodePlex to generate my resource files and now everything is ok